# How to delete a 2D array in Objective-C (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, cocoa

I want to have a simple 2D **C** type array as `x[ 10][20] ;` and want to delete it when needed to free memory but cocoa does not have delete method.   What is the best way? ( Just as performance issue)

Comment: you dont have to delete the array if your creating it on the stack like I understood your example. If you created the array with malloc then it is deleted with free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't free your memory because the memory was allocated on the stack by just declaring your array. Memory will then be freed when leaving the method. You should free your memory though if is was allocated on the heap using the C malloc function.

Have a look to this [doc](http://staff.um.edu.mt/csta1/courses/lectures/csa2060/c8a.html). This explains everything about C memory management.